# Codeginiter pagination adding extra results per page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codigniter application running which I have added pagination to the the results page. I have an issue in that the page gives the first 5 results but then subsequent pages add 5 more results on each page eventually giving a page full of results.

This is my controller code for the pagination

```
$paginatedFiles = array();
    if($ert<count($result)){
    $paginatedFiles = array_slice($result, $ert, $ert + 5, true);
    }else{
        $paginatedFiles = array_slice($result, $ert, count($result), true);
    }
    
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "properties/index";
    $config["total_rows"] = count($result);
    $config["per_page"] = 5;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    
    $this->load->view('properties',[
                'address_result'=>$paginatedFiles,
                'keyword'=>$sel_keyword,
                'property_type'=>$this->input->post('property_type'),
                'sqft' => $this->input->post('sqft'),
                'acres' => $this->input->post('acres'),
                'frlh' => $this->input->post('frlh'),
                'links'=>$this->pagination->create_links()
                
                ]);
```

I think it is this line but I cannot work out how to solve it.

```
$paginatedFiles = array_slice($result, $ert, $ert + 5, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed this line changing to:

```
$paginatedFiles = array_slice($result, $ert, 5, true);
```